# SQL Server Management Studio - Query using text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, text, ssms

Let's say I have a text file that has the following lines

```
102
333
534
```

Then, in my SQL table, I have a few different columns:

```
  AutoID | Name     | Description
  --------------------------------------         
    102  | Jackson  | [Description Here]  
    241  | Edward   | [Description Here]  
    333  | Timothy  | [Description Here]  
    437  | Nikky    | [Description Here]  
    534  | Jeremy   | [Description Here]
```

Is there anyway I can parse the text file through SQL Server Management Studio so that it will query the table and pull out every **row** that has a column (`AutoID`, in this case) that matches a line in the text file (Note, I only want the rows from a table that I would specify)?

This way I could edit them or update the rows that only match IDs in the text file.

The rows displayed in management studio would look like this.

```
  AutoID | NAME     | Description
  --------------------------------------
    102  | Jackson  | [Description Here]
    333  | Timothy  | [Description Here]
    534  | Jeremy   | [Description Here]
```

Comment: Load the data into a temporary table and use that for your querying.

Comment: @GordonLinoff And how would I accomplish that? Could you post a sample script?

Comment: . . Use the import wizard in SSMS.

Comment: But how would I go about doing the actual query? I've never had to query one table using another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--What you need to do is import the text file into a table in your SQL database, and then compare its values to the table you want to query (which I have called AutoIDTest in my example).

--Using your example data, I've put together the following code that accomplishes this process.

--1. I created a destination table for the text file's values called TextImport.  I've called the test text file E:\TestData.txt.  Additionally, I'm assuming this text file only has one column, autoID.

--2. Then, I imported the data into the destination table using the BULK INSERT statement.

--3. Finally, I compared the data in TextImport to the table from which you are seeking values using an INNER JOIN statement.

```
CREATE TABLE AutoIDTest ---Create test table.  Since your first column doesn't have a name, I'm calling it ID. I'm assuming AutoID and ID are both of type int.
    (
    ID int,
    AutoID int,
    Name varchar(25),
    Description varchar(50)
    )

INSERT INTO AutoIDTest -- Populate test table
VALUES
    ( 1, 102, 'Jackson', 'Description1'),
    ( 2, 241, 'Edward', 'Description2'),
    ( 3, 333, 'Timothy', 'Description3'),
    ( 4, 437, 'Nikky', 'Description4'),
    ( 5, 534, 'Jeremy', 'Description5')


CREATE TABLE TextImport --Create destination table for text file.
    (
    AutoID varchar(20),
    )

BULK INSERT TextImport --Load Data from text file into TextImport table
   FROM 'E:\TestData.txt'  ---The name and location of my test text file.
   WITH
      (
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'  
      );

SELECT   ---Produce Output Data
    ID,
    t1.AutoID,
    Name,
    Description
FROM
    AutoIDTest AS t1
INNER JOIN
    TextImport AS t2
    ON t1.autoID = cast(t2.autoID AS int) --convert varchar to int
```

## OUTPUT

```
--    ID          AutoID      Name                      Description
--    --------- ----------- ------------------------- -------------------
--    1           102         Jackson                   Description1
--    3           333         Timothy                   Description3
--    5           534         Jeremy                    Description5
```